# Incluir en una consulta SQL un campo de otra tabla con una condición

Tags: sql, sql-server

estoy trabajando con SQLServer. Tengo la siguiente consulta sencilla:

```
SELECT fec_emis,a.art_des, a.co_art FROM demo.dbo.art a 
    INNER JOIN demo.dbo.reng_com r ON a.co_art=r.co_art 
    INNER JOIN demo.dbo.compras c ON r.fact_num=c.fact_num
```

Pero ahora necesito añadir un campo que está en otra tabla, este campo lo obtengo individualmente con la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT TOP 1 tasa_v,fecha FROM tasas WHERE co_mone='$' 
AND fecha<=GETDATE() ORDER BY fecha DESC
```

Esta ultima consulta lo que hace es darme la tasa más reciente según una fecham que en este caso es la actual (GETDATE()), pero ahora necesito que me de esa tasa pero con la fecha que tengo en la otra consulta (fec_emis), o sea, que me haga la primera consulta pero qu me incluya estos campos del registro cuya fecha sea más cercana a la fecha de amisión.

Edito:

Estructura de las tablas:

```
Tabla TASAS:
tasa_v
fecha 
co_mone

Tabla compras 
fec_emis
fact_num

Tabla reng_com 
fact_num
co_art

Tabla art
co_art
```

Comment: Sería bueno que en estos casos agregaras las estructuras de cada tabla y un ejemplo de los datos de entrada y la salida esperada. Minímamente: `fec_emis` de que tabla es? puedes publicar la estructura de `tasas`? Saludos.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. Ya añadí la estructura.

Answer (score 0):

En este caso, como tu subconsulta devuelve un solo registro, alcanza con que la trates como si fuera un campo mas, pasandole a la misma el campo por el cual queres filtrar:

```
SELECT fec_emis,
       a.art_des,
       a.co_art,
       (SELECT TOP 1 tasa_v FROM tasas WHERE co_mone='$' 
           AND fecha<=fec_emis ORDER BY fecha DESC) as tasa
FROM demo.dbo.art a 
INNER JOIN demo.dbo.reng_com r ON a.co_art=r.co_art 
INNER JOIN demo.dbo.compras c ON r.fact_num=c.fact_num
```

Fijate que de la subconsulta saque el campo fecha, porque una subconsulta no puede devolver dos campos. Si necesitas que devuelva dos campos, la cosa es un poco mas complicada. Se pueden hacer dos selects (algo que seria poco performarte) o usar un with (si fuera una vista para no tener que recorrer todo lo mismo dos veces).

Comment: Sería algo así entonces:

  <blink>SELECT fec_emis,
       a.art_des,
       a.co_art,
       (SELECT TOP 1 tasa_v FROM tasas WHERE co_mone='$' 
           AND fecha<=fec_emis ORDER BY fecha DESC) as tasa,
       (SELECT TOP 1 fecha FROM tasas WHERE co_mone='$' 
           AND fecha<=fec_emis ORDER BY fecha DESC) as fecha
FROM demo.dbo.art a 
INNER JOIN demo.dbo.reng_com r ON a.co_art=r.co_art 
INNER JOIN demo.dbo.compras c ON r.fact_num=c.fact_num  </blink>

Comment: Exacto.. no quedaba claro en la pregunta si querias solo uno o los dos. @RaymondMedina

Comment: Si, necesito los dos, de esta manera tu me señalas que "algo que seria poco performance". Esto lo estoy haciendo desde un sistema en VFP, yo lo solucioné de la siguiente manera:

1ero: Dejo la consulta como la tenía (sin hacer la subconsulta a TASAS.
2do: Hago un SCAN al cursor y hago la consulta a TASAS por cada registro del cursor, y lo actualizo

Ahora mi pregunta es, respecto a performance, ¿de que manera sería mejor?

Comment: es poco performante porque estas haciendo el mismo query exactamente dos veces. igual todo depende del tamaño de la tabla que tiene las tasas. tal vez con un buen indice superes ese problema.

Answer (score 0):

Pese a que la respuesta de gbianchi es correcta, quiero ofrecer una que puede ser mas optimizada, especialmente si vas a requerir más de una columna de "tasas", y es la siguiente:

```
SELECT fec_emis,a.art_des, a.co_art, t.fecha, t.tasa_v FROM demo.dbo.art a 
INNER JOIN demo.dbo.reng_com r ON a.co_art=r.co_art 
INNER JOIN demo.dbo.compras c ON r.fact_num=c.fact_num 
INNER JOIN tasas t ON NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tasas t2 where t.fecha < 
t2.fecha and t2.fecha < c.fec_emis) And t.fecha < c.fec_emis
```